# force strong parameter value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

how to insert parameter value manually from controller,
this my controller

```
def new
  @new_post = Post.new(params[:title])
end

def create
  @new_post = Post.new(new_post_params)
  if @new_post.save
    flash[:success] = 'Post created!'
    redirect_to home_url
  else
    flash[:danger] = @new_post.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    redirect_to home_url
  end
end

private
def new_post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(
    :title, 
    poster_id: current_user.id, 
    poster_name: current_user.name
 )
```

end

my form view like this

```
form_for @new_post do |f|
   f.text_area :title
end
```

tired using this method, poster_id and poster_name still blank

```
    def new_post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(
      :title, 
      poster_id: current_user.id, 
      poster_name: current_user.name
   )
   end
```

Comment: how about `params.require(:post).permit(
      :title).merge({
      poster_id: current_user.id, 
      poster_name: current_user.name})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title).merge(
  { 
    poster_id: current_user.id,
    poster_name: current_user.name
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   def new_post_params
     params[:post][:poster_id] = current_user.id
     params[:post][:poster_name] = current_user.name 
     params.require(:post).permit(
        :title, 
        :poster_id,
        :poster_name
      )     
   end
```